# Median of three numbers... but not the typical way

Tags: elementary-functions, median

Let's say I have three numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$. To find the median of these three numbers, you order them from least to greatest, then take the second (middle) number. For example, if the numbers were 6, 5, and 10, I would order them as 5, 6, 10, then take the second number, which is 6.

However... let's say the median is the function $m(a,b,c)$. How do I write this function in terms of elementary functions composed of a, b, and c? (No piecewises allowed).

A similar example: let's say you wanted to write $\min(a,b)$ in terms of elementary functions. One way would be to take the midpoint, then subtract half the distance between the two points. In other words, $\dfrac{a+b}{2}-\dfrac{|a-b|}{2}$.

I can't seem to figure one out for the median though.

Comment: We can express $\text{min}(a, b, c)=\text{min}(\text{min}(a, b), c)$ in terms of elementary functions, and similarly max, too. Then the median for three numbers is $a+b+c-\text{min}(a, b, c)-\text{max}(a, b, c)$.

Comment: @JoshuaWoo That's nice! I asked a friend and they got that too. I also found one that's quite elegant (I have no idea why it works), but it does use the sign function: $\dfrac{a+b+(|c-a|+|c-b|)\operatorname{sign}(a-b)}{2}$